# how to insert post to my blog in server by Service Account without any manual login

Tags: google-api, blogger, service-accounts

I want to insert a post to my blog by php in my server cron so there there is no any manual login.
I have create Service Account and can get the post by `$data = $blogger->posts->get('6284611449262742568', '4655425391398964038');`
However, insert post fail with following error.
`data = $blogger->posts->insert('6284611449262742568', $mypost);`

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/6284611449262742568/posts:
>   (403) We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this
>   resource.' in /xx/lab/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110

Stack trace:

```
#0 /xx/lab/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request), Object(Google_Client))
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 /xx/lab/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /xx/lab/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#4 /xx/lab/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php(563): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Goog in /xx/lab/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 110
```

How can I have the permission to insert/modify post to my blog?

Answer (score 2):

Service accounts are not supported with Blogger. Blogger requires people using Blogger to agree to our Terms of Service, and Service Accounts can't accept them.

A work around would be to use Normal Oauth2 Authentication.  Authentication your code once save the refresh token and use that in your cron script.