# Add Post With Google Api to Blogger With Service account keys

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to create php script that post article to Blogger using Google API. I'm using library `google/apiclient:^2.0`. I'm choosing to use service account keys. Here's my codes:

```
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/../../credentials/BeMine92929929.json');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Be Mine');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Blogger::BLOGGER);
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
    // I dump $token here, and it's available. token generation is success.

    $service = new Google_Service_Blogger($client);
    $blog = $service->blogs->getByUrl('http://bemine.blogspot.com');

    //this is part for sending post into blogger, which is getting
    //error
    $post = new Google_Service_Blogger_Post();
    $post->setTitle('Coba Post Artikel Kedua');
    $post->setContent('Artikel kedua ini dikirim melalui layanan Blogger api.');
    $service->posts->insert('Here Is My Blog ID', $post);

    //If I comment posting part, and try to get list article of
    //my blog, It success.   
    $posts = $service->posts->listPosts($blog->getId());
    //file_put_contents('/tmp/anarky.txt', var_export($posts, true));
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

The response when I try to post article :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "We're sorry, but you don't have permission to access this resource."
 }
}
```

What do I miss Need your advise, thank you.

Comment: fyi I've enabled Blogger API v3

Comment: ... and I want to execute/run the script from cli `php -f RunBlogger.php`

Comment: Says here something about Blogger not supporting service accounts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119637/how-to-insert-post-to-my-blog-in-server-by-service-account-without-any-manual-lo